# What is the maximum range of the very best Starfleet transporter in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek

They supposedly have a 40,000 km (about a 25,000 mile) range, but over the years people have been transported to far greater distances. In the reboot Star Trek (2009) as example, Scotty and Kirk are shown to beam aboard Enterprise while it's traveling at warp, light years away. How can this be?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the ability to tranport inter-planetary distances was shown to be possible in the original Trek Series, in the episode "[Assignment Earth](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/55.htm)",

> **SPOCK:** *The beam is originating at least one thousand light years away.*
>
> **SCOTT:** *No transporter beam can reach that far, not even in our century.*  (Kirk enters.)
>
> **KIRK:** *Something is shaking us apart.*
>
> **SCOTT:** *It's locked, it's locked our circuits wide open.*
>
> (One of the transporter pads has activated.)
>
> **KIRK:** *You're right. Something is beaming aboard.*

Given that Khan transports from Earth to Klingon in the rebooted Trek film, and that the Klingon border is described in [Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation-Klingon_border) as being "**a thousand light years away from Earth**", this also the answer to your question.

### 1000 Light years is the farthest we see anyone transport, however there's no evidence that this is the upper range.

Comment: Yes I remember 'Assignment Earth'. I actually watched it when it first aired. That was Gary 7, a perfect human bred and raised by a hidden, highly advanced civilization that would remain unknown even in Kirk's time if I remember correctly. A thousand+ light years with a Federation transporter!? I need to check this. I can't see that being topped.

Comment: BTW Gary had an awesome cat.

Comment: I haven't seen that one so let me get my mind around this; After his attack on Starfleet HQ, Khan escaped by transporting from Earth to Kronos, a thousand light years away, using a Klingon PORTABLE transporter device!? Why not just get rid of starships and call this superior, apparently unlimited transport ability 'The Abrams Effect'?

Comment: @morgan - I'm pretty sure Gary Seven wasn't human, he was humanoid

Comment: I just pulled up Memory Alpha. It had this to say about him; Gary Seven was a Human male whose ancestors were abducted from Earth around 4000 BC. (we don't know by whom) He held the position of Class One Supervisor, known as Supervisor 194. He was grown and conditioned in some way which allowed him to have a completely healthy and flawless body; furthermore he was insensitive to the impact of the Vulcan nerve pinch. His cat was named 'Isis'.

Comment: @Morgan Khan ain't sharin'. Also, it might be that there's some form of relay system he managed to set up (bouncing from transporter to transporter across the galaxy). But yeah, good question.

Comment: If I remember the 'plot' of Star Trek (2009) correctly, the long range transportation there was actually an implementation of Transwarp Beaming, for which Spock brought the magic numbers back from the future. They would have been the "very best" transporters in the Star Trek (2009) universe, but not TOS/TNG/et cetera.

Comment: Possible, but not with Federation technology. As Morgan pointed out, Gary Seven is part of some incredibly advanced organization that also does intentional time travel interference and so on, a bit like a tame Time Lord from Doctor Who, so his transporter is way beyond what Federation technology can do.